# Im trying to install Box2D to python but i didn't succeed

Tags: python, installation, box2d

Me and my friend are trying to create a simulator based on python so we wanted to use Box2D.
im trying to install box2d to python 3.6 using `pip  install Box2D` but it shows me this -

````
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/7b/ddb96fea1fa5b24f8929714ef483f64c33e9649e7aae066e5f5023ea46a/Box2D-2.3.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: Box2D
    Running setup.py install for Box2D ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0tson6el\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0tson6el\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-preupzga\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0tson6el\Box2D\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Using setuptools (version 42.0.2).
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\Box2D.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    copying library\Box2D\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
    copying library\Box2D\b2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\Box2D\b2
    running build_ext
    building 'Box2D._Box2D' extension
    swigging Box2D\Box2D.i to Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp
    swig.exe -python -c++ -IBox2D -small -O -includeall -ignoremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library\Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D\Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D\Box2D.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0tson6el\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0tson6el\\Box2D\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-preupzga\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.```

i tried a few solutions i found online but none of them worked.
thanks for the helpers.
````

Comment: One problem could be that the last release was 2016. And python 3.6 was released after this. So it could be that this library has no support for python 3.6. You could try to use an older python version. Another problem could be since this is a cpp library, that the installation process is more complicated and you need to install librarys manually

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using pymunk, its pretty good from what ive seen.
its not exectly an answer to my question but it might help someone